# Show f need not be continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continuity, examples-counterexamples

If the functions $f_k$ are lower semicontinuous, $f_k \rightarrow f$ pointwise, and $f_{k+1} \geq f_k(x)$ then $f$ is lower semicontinuous. Show that $f$ need not be continuous even if the $f_k$ are continuous.

I proved the first statement by showing if the hypothesis hold then, $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}inf f(x) \geq \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}inf f_k(x) \geq f_k(x_0) $.

Answer (score 1):

For example, if we take $f_k:[0,1] \to \Bbb R$, try the sequence $f_k(x) = 1 - x^k$.  What is its pointwise limit?

Comment: Is the point wise limit 1 for x=1 and 0 for everything else? Therefore, although $f_k$ is continuous and lowersemicontinuous it's limit function is not. @Omnomnomnom

Comment: You have it backwards: the pointwise limit is $0$ for $x = 1$ and $0$ for everything else.  Besides that, yes; you have the right idea.